# How to generate image thumbnails from .docx documents using pywin32

Tags: python, ms-word, vsto, pywin32

I am using Mark Hammond's pywin32 extensions with Microsoft Word 2013. My goal is simple:
I need to get the -first- page of any given .docx file and save it as a jpeg file (or any other image file) essentially generating a thumbnail.

How should I go about it?

This is my progress so far:

```
from time import sleep
import win32com.client as win32

def word():
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open("myFile.docx")
    word.Visible = False
    sleep(1)
    ...
    ## CODE I NEED ##
    ...
    doc.Close(False)
    word.Application.Quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    word()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible to save it as PDF file... think if this would not be ok for you.

Comment: @KazJaw I'm already saving it as a PDF file. I just need to save a thumbnail as well.

Answer (score 2):

The MS Office's documents are saved in OOXML format which basically is a zipped archive of "different files".

To extract the thumb, just look in the ZIP (ok, docx) archive for a file named "thumbnail" with whatever extension. (Currently is either thumbnail.emf (for docx), wmf (for xlsx) and jpeg (for pptx)). Also, be advised that the thumb (the file) can be missing if the user chose when he save the file from Word/Excel/PowerPoint to NOT include the thumbnail.